# iPhone 4s can't use office internet (Squid Proxy)

Tags: ios, iphone

I've configured iPhone 4s to use our office wifi and specified a squid proxy and its authentication data (tested and working on computers and my colleague android phone) but when I connect to office's wifi a "Login" completely white screen appears.
How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can apply a configuration profile containing the Wi-Fi details, including the proxy details.  This can be done with iPhone Configuration Utility, Apple Configurator or an MDM solution.

Answer (score 0):

On the phone, go to advanced WiFi network settings and put the HTTP Proxy settings there.

It can happen quite often for the iOS to not be able to detect the proxy.

Comment: I already said in the post that I've entered proxy details in wi fi configuration :)